# Weka classifier MultilayerPerceptron

Tags: classification, weka

I have a problem with **weka =/.**

I'm using **weka** for data mining time series with **neural network**, in other words: the classifier MultilayerPerceptron.

my configuration is `"MultilayerPerceptron -L 0.3 -M 0.1 -N 1000 -V 0 -S 0 -E 20 -H a"`

There is the problem... **the weka never ends**.

I have **1904** instances and **18** attributes, corresponding to five days of time series, is not much data =/.

the last time the **weka** run for 8 days and it stop to run but don't give me a result.

any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I have run a MultilayerPerceptron using 10-fold Cross-Validation using a generated dataset containing 1904 instances and 18 attributes.

Given the configuration outlined above, each fold took 12 seconds on my PC and completed quite fine.  Given the size of the dataset and the number of training runs, it shouldn't really take too long to train the MLP.

Perhaps there is something up with the data that you are using (Perhaps you could supply the arff header and some sample lines) or the system stopped training for some reason.  You could try on another computer, but I'm not sure if that would resolve the issue.

I can't see why it would take 8 days to train a network like this.  You probably don't need to wait that long before realising that there is an issue in the training. :)

Hope this Helps!